# MSMQ error while trying to access remote private queue.Cannot open queue. (hr=unknown hr (-2147023071))

Tags: java, message-queue, msmq

MSMQ error while trying to access remote private queue.

```
Exception: Cannot open queue. (hr=unknown hr (-2147023071))
```

I already added these two:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\AllowNonauthenticatedRPC` and set the value to `1`.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient` and set it to `1`

Answer (score 0):

-2147023071 is 0x80070721 which isn't an MSMQ-specific error code (as they start 0xC00Exxxx). I believe this is a security-related error code.

As you are receiving messages from a remote queue, you are using the RPC protocol so this article will help:

[Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

Sending a message uses the MSMQ protocol and so does not have the same problems.

Comment: Thanks.I will go through it.I'm not able to open the queue due to this error.I'm not able to send or receive the messages due to this.

Comment: What are the queue permissions?

Comment: We purchased JIntegra and Configured DCOM for Remote Access to resolve the connection issue.Thanks John for your help.